# RevMob Banner : adobe air - flash CS6 - Auto dismissing issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, revmob, revmobads

In my adobe air application, i've managed to implement Revmob ads:  Rewarded video and banners. 
I'm still in my testing mode, so when i run the game i will get the blue Revmob Banner at the bottom of the screen as expected. The first problem is, whenever i click on the ad, it will popup a window, and in 2 seconds it disappears without even loading anything, and my game keeps running in the background! 
I've tried to trace and see if the ad is getting dissmissed, but i didn't get any trace :

```
case RevMobAdsEvent.BANNER_DISMISSED:
                {

                    trace( "RevMob banner dismissed");
                    break;
                }
```

- should i manually pause the game whenever the user clicks on the banner? or would it automatically pause? because it seems that the game continues!
- When is BANNER_DISSMISSED called?
- If i have to manually pause, how can i do so ? Note that i have timers running, and unsing stage.framerate = 0 will stop the game but not the timers.
- Is it normal that the window automatically disappears? how can i test anything?

Answer (score 3):

Hi [Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503394/elias-rahme),

We have test our SDK and could not reproduce this issue with the banner click. 
Could you please check if you are using the latest version available [here](https://revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk/air/9.2.1/download)?
In case you are with the latest version, could you send us the log shown when calling

`revmob.printEnvironmentInformation();`

and also your flash version?

About the questions you raised:

1. Yes, you should manually pause the game when the user clicks on any of our ads. You can check [here](https://revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk/air#content-listeners) all listeners fired when a user clicks in any ads, always ending in "_CLICKED"
2. BANNER_DISMISSED is called if you call

`revmob.hideBanner();` or `revmob.releaseBanner();`

3. Each app has it's own way of pausing itself, like when a user hits pause button, you should probably use the same logic you use in that scenario
4. No, that's not the behavior we are expecting. You should see a webview with our message saying the click in your ad was successful, if you provide the information asked above in this answer, we will have a more close look into it

Hope to have cleared your doubts, and as always, should you have any further questions, just contact us.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you just please point out where can i find the log ? the revmob.printEnvironmentInformation(); , where can i find the output..Sorry if it's a silly question but i'm really new to AS3 and flash

Comment: I managed to find and create the flashlog.txt file, plz find it here ! https://jpst.it/MPLc

Comment: Hy ,

Today and out of nowhere, whenever i click on the banner in my IOS application, safari will open up, the first link i see is **android.revmob.com** and then redirected to **adtags.revmob.com/success**   and i will see a page in safari stating : " Congratulations ..." 

- Is this the expected behavior ? when i click the banner , safari opens up instantly ?
- Is it normal to see the first link as android.revmob.com ? even though it's an IOS app and it's an iPhone?

Comment: Yes, it is common to see android.revmob.com even though is a iOS device